# How to make the width of an AbstractDialogFragment extended class match the window width?

Tags: java, android

I'm displaying a dialog in my mobile application, using an AbstractDialogFragment extended class. How do I set the width to match the size of the screen?

I've already tryed to override the onResume() method and setting the width and height, getting the window's dimensions, but i'd like to set just the width.

Here is what I tryed:

```java
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    Window window = getDialog().getWindow();

    // ...
    // get window width and height
    // ...

    window.setLayout(width, height);
    window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
}
```

I expect the dialogs width to be relative to the screen width.

Answer (score 0):

you can set height of dialogue using this code or you can check [this](https://zocada.com/android-full-screen-dialogs-using-dialogfragment/)

```
Window window = dialog.getWindow();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = window.getAttributes();
        wlp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        window.setAttributes(wlp);
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

Comment: I tryed this using getDialog() instead of dialog, but it didn't change the width.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
Dialog dialog = getDialog();
if (dialog != null) {
  int width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
  int height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
  Objects.requireNonNull(dialog.getWindow())
      .setFlags(
          WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
          WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
  Objects.requireNonNull(dialog.getWindow()).setLayout(width, height);
}
```

Comment: Same thing :/  I ran it in debug mode and width and height are -1. Any ideas?